# Combine multiple data files in a single plot

Tags: plot, fortran, gnuplot

I have several data files produced from a Fortran code. All the data files are following the same style regarding their names, that is: data###.out, where ### starts from 001 and ends to 500. I know that in order to read and plot several data files in `gnuplot` I must use

```
plot for [i=1:500] sprintf('data00%i.out', i) u 1:2 w d lc rgb 'black'
```

However, this only works until data009.out. For 010 to 099 it should skip one zero and from 100 to 999 two zeros. How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pad with zeroes an integer printed with three digits, the correct format is `%03i`. Try:

```
plot for [i=1:500] sprintf('data%03i.out', i) u 1:2 w d lc rgb 'black'
```